# Computation of contour integral without winding numbers.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to solve problem $3$ on page 108 in Ahlfors. The problem asks to compute $\int_{\left\vert z \right\vert = 2} \frac{dz}{z^2 - 1}$ so I am trying to do so without the use of winding numbers, which isn't introduced until later sections.

I first used partial fraction decomposition to write $\frac{1}{z^2 - 1}$ as $\frac{1}{2} \cdot (\frac{1}{z-1} - \frac{1}{z+1})$. From here, it's clear that the integral is $0$ if we resort to winding numbers. Since I was unable to compute the integral using elementary methods, I resorted to reading [this solution](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~brubaker/docs/8701-F13/hw4-solns.pdf). However, I don't understand how they changed the path of integration from $\left\vert z \right\vert = 2$ to $\left\vert z - 1 \right\vert = 1$ because when $z = -2$, $\left\vert z - 1 \right\vert = \left\vert -3 \right\vert = 3 \ne 1$.

Comment: I don't have the text. Can you use the Cauchy theorem?

Comment: @SeanRoberson Cauchy's integral formula and Cauchy's theorem haven't been introduced at this point. All we know is what a line integral is and that the integral of $\frac{1}{z-a}dz$ taken over a circle centered at $a$ is $2\pi i$

Comment: So you aren't allowed to use the fact that $\oint_C 1/z\, dz = 2\pi i$ for any positively oriented Jordan curve about $0$? If not, why not just evaluate each integral directly, e.g. use substitution $z = 2e^{it}$ and so $\oint_{|z|=2} \frac{1}{z-1} dz  = 2i\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{it}}{2e^{it}-1}\, dt = \left[i\log(2e^{it}-1)\right]_0^{2\pi} = 2\pi i.$ I don't know how to account for the manipulation used in the solutions with just the information you provided - it looks like the solutions are homework solutions? They are probably using extra information not yet introduced in Ahlfors.

Comment: Ah I didn't think to use the derivative of log. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
\begin{align}
\int_{\left\vert z \right\vert = 2} \frac{dz}{z^2 - 1}&=\frac12\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\frac{2ie^{it} }{2e^{it}-1}-\frac{2ie^{it} }{2e^{it}+1}\right)\,dt\\ \ \\
&=\frac12\left.\left(\log(2e^{it} -1)-\log(2e^{it}+1)\right)\right|_0^{2\pi}\\ \ \\
&=0-0=0
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly general argument you will probably find useful.

Note that the function $\frac{1}{z^2-1}$ is analytic everywhere except the points $1$ and $-1$. This means that we can **move** the contour so long as the singular points ($1$ and $-1$) remain inside the domain. We can deform the contour into an infinity-looking domain, where the touch point is the origin, and the center of the two circles located in the infinity are $1$ and $-1$. Because those are essentially two different circles, the integral around the contour is equal to the sum of the integrals around the two circles. These two circle's new contours are $|z-1| = 1$ and $|z+1| = 1$ (note they still intersect at the origin). Now, we can use the formula you know regarding $2 \pi i$, which would then yield the answer of $0$.

Comment: And this leads to the homotopic version of the Cauchy theorem.